# How to get a list of values with jquery each function

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

I'm trying to get data value from an `<li data-nid="1">` tag. The `<li>` list is generated from an `Ajax` query response.

```
$.each(data.notifications.detail,function(index, element){
$('#notifications_list').append('<li id="element" data-nid ='+element.id+'><a>'+element.texte+'</a></li>');
});
```

to recover value, I tried the following method :

```
var array = new Array();
  $( "#element").each(function() {
        var id = $( this ).data( "nid" );
        array.push(id);
   });
```

But i'm always getting just one element, and its always the first one. So maybe someone clarify me the situation.

Comment: `id` must be unique.

Comment: `$( "#element li")` use this assuming that element is ul id

Comment: No, element is  `<li> ` id.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly you cannot have multiple elements with the same `id`, hence the point of using an `each()` on an id selector is completely redundant. You should change the `id` to a `class`.

To create the array of values from the appended elements you can simply use `map()`. Try this:

```
$.each(data.notifications.detail, function(index, element){
    $('#notifications_list').append('<li class="element" data-nid="' + element.id + '"><a>' + element.texte + '</a></li>');
});

var array = $(".element").map(function() {
    return $(this).data("nid");
}).get();
```

Also note that you could create the array of values in the same `each()` loop as you append the new `li` elements, like this:

```
var array = [];
$.each(data.notifications.detail, function(index, element){
    array.push(element.id);
    $('#notifications_list').append('<li class="element" data-nid="' + element.id + '"><a>' + element.texte + '</a></li>');
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It was helpful :).

Answer (score 0):

A html "id" must be unique.
You can filter using your parent `<ul>` and then use `children()` or `filter('li')`

```
$("#notification_list").children().each(function() {
    var id = $( this ).data( "nid" );
    array.push(id);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Because `id` is unique, use `class` and it will be working fine.